# Rave Reports Master Detail giving evariantoverflowerror

Tags: delphi, rave-reports

I have a report that uses a master and a child query - the master selects three fields in a group by: billstatus, oscategory(server or workstation) and groupname

The child query selects a bunch of information from the same view with no group by.

I used the rave wizard to create a master detail report, linking the parent and child on groupname and oscategory.

I have done this for many reports in the past... but this one is giving me fits...

The queries will open without a problem, I can preview the report in Rave using F9 - but when I try to RUN the program to generate the report, it gives me the following error:
class EVariantOverflowError with message 'Overflow while converting variant of type (Decimal) into type (Currency).

I have no decimal values in the select list, however, the queries do use a couple of parameters: groupname, DateStart, and DateEnd

Any ideas would be helpful at this point as I can't even run the report with no fields when I set it up as master/detail with the two queries

master:

```
SELECT groupname, oscategory, billstatus
FROM MyView
WHERE groupname = :groupname
AND lastcheckin >= :StartDate
AND firstcheckin < :EndDate
AND BillStatus <> 'Do Not Bill'
GROUP BY groupname, oscategory, billstatus
```

child:

```
SELECT machine_groupid, agentguid, machName, groupname, firstcheckin, lastcheckin, currentuser, lastloginname, lastreboot, agentversion, contactname, contactemail, 
contactphone, contactnotes, enabletickets, enableremotecontrol, enablechat, loginname, credentialname, primarykserver, secondarykserver, quickcheckinsecs, agenttempdir, 
manufacturer, productname, machineversion, sysserialnumber, chassisserialnumber, chassisassettag, busspeed, maxmemorysize, maxmemoryslots, chassismanufacturer, 
chassistype, chassisversion, motherboardmanufacturer, motherboardproductcode, motherboardversion, motherboardserialnumber, computername, subnetmask, 
defaultgateway, dnsserver1, dnsserver2, dnsserver3, dnsserver4, dhcpenabled, dhcpserver, winsenabled, primarywinsserver, secondarywinsserver, connectiongatewayip, 
ostype, osinfo, majorversion, minorversion, macaddr, loginnamemach, billstatus, oscategory, cpudesc, cpuspeed, cpucount, totalram,
(manufacturer + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(productname))) as displaypc, 
('CPU/Memory: ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), cpuspeed) + ' MHZ x ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), cpucount) + ' / ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), totalram) + ' Mb') as cpuspecs, 
(ostype + ' ' + osinfo) as osdisplay, 
(cpudesc + '/' + maxmemorysize + ' x ' + maxmemoryslots) as memorydisplay, 
('Ip Address: ' + ipaddress) as ipinformation
FROM MyView
WHERE groupname = :groupname
and machName is not null
AND lastcheckin >= :StartDate
AND firstcheckin < :EndDate
AND BillStatus <> 'Do Not Bill'
```

Answer (score 1):

It was my date formatting - I was using the StartOfTheMonth function which returns an extended value instead of a date value.  I added a 'DateOf() around the function and everything worked nicely

Thanks all  :-)